# When I add a row of a certain cell id to a UITableView, it returns an empty row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableView` with different cell ID's. What I'm trying to do is add a row when the button is selected. Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *cellID;

    ...
    else if ([indexPath row] == 5) {
        cellID = @"rowFive";
    }
    else if ([indexPath row] >= self.myNum && [indexPath row] <= self.myNum) {
        cellID = @"rowSix";
    }
    else if ([indexPath row] == self.myNum + 1) {
        cellID = @"rowSeven";
    }
    else if ([indexPath row] == self.myNum + 2) {
        cellID = @"rowEight";
    }

    customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[customCell alloc] init];
    }

    return cell;
 }

- (IBAction)addRow:(id)sender
{
    self.myNum ++;
    self.numberOfRows ++;
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

What happens is when I select the button, a row is added, but nothing inside of it. It's just an empty row, and it doesn't get loaded with the cell ID of `rowSix`.

When I delete the if statement of `cell == nil` if I then I select the button, the app crashes with the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier (null) - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

Comment: This is a better question because of the error message.  I can help with the logic, but please delete either this one or this duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845970/add-row-of-a-certain-cell-id-to-a-uitableview-returns-an-empty-row).

Comment: Just deleted the other post

Comment: Great thanks.  If the user presses this add button say, 9 times, you'd like to see 9 rows?  And you like those rows to be populated with a different type of cell (with a different reuse identifier) for each row up to some max?  Like if these were reuse ids, then you'd like: one, two, three, four, five, six, six, six, and so on ??

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I set `numberOfRows` to 9 in `viewDidLoad`. What I'm trying to do, is, when the user selects a button, it should add another cell with the identifier `rowSix`.

Comment: How many rows  there are after initializing at the beginning?

Comment: There are 10 rows at startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table views have datasources, and datasources are almost always (lets say always) arrays.  The array describes at least what is essential to each row.  So first, declare the table's datasource (aka model):

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *rowArray;
```

Lets say for simplicity that the only thing needed to describe your rows is the reuse identifier.  It seems from comments that you want the table to begin with 10 rows, those up to the eighth have unique reuse identifiers and the additional have @"rowSix" as their identifiers.  If that's so, here's how to initialize the datasource in viewDidLoad:

```
self.rowArray = [@[@"rowOne", @"rowTwo", @"rowThree", @"rowFour", @"rowFive", @"rowSix",
    @"rowSeven", @"rowEight", @"rowSix", @"rowSix"] mutableCopy];
```

This long-ish datasource definition now simplifies the rest of your code.  For example, `numberOfRowsInSection` now looks like this:

```
return self.rowArray.count;
```

And `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is even better:

```
NSString *cellID = self.rowArray[indexPath.row];
// delete error-prone, unreadable, slow if else if else if logic
customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Even your button push logic improves:

```
- (IBAction)addRow:(id)sender {
    // probably no longer need self.myNum
    // probably no longer need self.numberOfRows
    [self.rowArray addObject:@"rowSix"];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Cool, right?

PS - this line...

```
else if ([indexPath row] >= self.myNum && [indexPath row] <= self.myNum)
```

... only tests if the indexPath.row is equal to self.myNum (not sure what that is), and wouldn't under any other circumstances set your cellID to @"rowSix".  the app crashes because execution slips through all of those if-else statements *without giving any value* to cellID.  But don't spend any effort fixing those conditionals... take this as confirmation that they should be replaced with a better design.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was trying this for the whole day!!

Comment: Instead of `[self.myTableView reloadData]`, I did `insertRowAtIndexPath...` cuz I want the animation. When I did that, the cells size changed to a very compact size. But when the cells went out of view, and came back, they were back to normal. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You may need to implement - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, returning the height of the particular custom cell.  Make sure that the table's delegate pointer is also set to the vc that implements this method.